# Symfony2 friendly url on form submission with GET

Tags: php, forms, symfony, methods, get

I have a problem when submitting a form and send the params with get method.

In browser address bar it shows not friendly url, like:
-http://www.myDomainApp.com/app_dev.php/user/list?limit=10&offset=0

and I expected some like:
-http://www.myDomainApp.com/app_dev.php/user/list/10/0

Anybody knows why, and how can I do the friendly url?

I found an explanation here of my problem, but I think this is not symfony 2.x.
PS : I am using yml files for routing not annotations.

Please help.

Comment: Solution ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413430/passing-route-url-format-to-symfony2-form-with-get-method/22430651?noredirect=1#22430651

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody knows why

Because that is how the form submission process is defined in the HTML specification.

> and how can I do the friendly url?

Process the form data and issue a 301 redirect from the server.